# Switching from a UITableview controller to a viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm just learning and playing with the apple Seismic XML example

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

I've got most of it figured out, but the one area I can't get past is, if I want to remove the tableview controller and create a view controller populated with a tableview.  I can get the tableview to appear fine, but no matter what I try I can never get it to populate.

In the viewdidload area I can setup the tableview, color the background, do whatever I want to do, but I seem to 'lose' control of it somehow.

In short, would someone please be able to give me the steps involved in correctly changing the tableviewcontroller to a viewcontroller with a tableview in the apple example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lian, you need to read the documentation on UITableViewController. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

I'm not sure what you mean by "remove the tableview controller and create a view controller populated with a tableview" or why you would want this configuration. If you're having trouble with populating the tableViewController, you just pass in the data, usually from an NSArray or NSDictionary in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You either need to select the UITableViewController template when you create the class file or include the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate if you're adding a tableView to a ViewController.

If you mean you want to change the view controller on screen, then you're looking to pop to another view using the navigation controller.